# Reversing bits of Python Numpy Array

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a numpy array of dtype uint16, how do I efficiently manipulate each element of the array so that the bits are reversed?

eg. 0001111010011100 -> 0011100101111000

The existing solutions on this website seem to suggest printing the number into a string which will be really slow for arrays.

---

Example of what I want to do:

```
test = np.array([128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]).astype(np.uint16)
out = reverse_bits(test)
print(out)
>> array([  256,   512,  1024,  2048,  4096,  8192, 16384, 32768], dtype=uint16)
```

Comment: I'm curious, why do you need to do this?

Comment: I have an image mask saved as a 16bit tiff where the bits are coded to represent different classes. I just wanted  a bijective way to visualise an image mask and "amplify" values with small differences.it wasn't strictly necessary as I am aware of alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will reverse bits in each element of an array.

```
def reverse_bits(x):

    x = np.array(x)
    n_bits = x.dtype.itemsize * 8

    x_reversed = np.zeros_like(x)
    for i in range(n_bits):
        x_reversed = (x_reversed << 1) | x & 1
        x >>= 1
    return x_reversed
```

Comment: This solves the problem but does not appear efficient.  Other options may include `packbits` at least.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one based off some old HAKMEM tricks.

```
def bitreverse16(x):
    x = ((x & 0x00FF) << 8) | ((x & 0xFF00) >> 8)
    x = ((x & 0x0F0F) << 4) | ((x & 0xF0F0) >> 4)
    x = ((x & 0x3333) << 2) | ((x & 0xCCCC) >> 2)
    x = ((x & 0x5555) << 1) | ((x & 0xAAAA) >> 1)
    return x
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this version.  I timed it about 6X faster than the `bitreverse16` and 20X faster than the `reverse_bits` function for the given example vector.

```
def reverse_bits2(x):
    dtype = np.asanyarray(x).dtype
    return np.flip(np.packbits(np.flip(np.unpackbits(x.view(np.uint8)))).view(dtype))
```